# C++ Homework Help (drawing a stick house including / \ )

Tags: c++

Am taking a intro to C++ college course and am stumped on a very simple task. I have to draw a house shape and the roof has to include the "/" and "\" in it. After I compile and run: something like this

```
cout <<"  /\ " <<endl;
cout <<" /  \ " <<endl;
```

it comes out missing the "/" and it looks like this

```
   /
  /
 /
 ======
```

Please advise and my textbook does not have info and I can find any resource to reference including the help function on my Bloodshed DevC++ 5.7.1.

Comment: \ is the escape character. You need to use `" /\\ "`.

Comment: `cout << "  /??/??/??/n /  ??/??/??/n/    ??/??/??/n======??/n??!    ??!??/n======??/n"` [live example](http://ideone.com/2scp8j)

Answer (score 6):

Because `\` indicates an escape sequence, such as `\n` for a newline.  Try:

```
cout << "/\\" << endl;
```

instead.